# Testing a Spring Boot Elastic Search application and loading context without starting ES-Instance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Since I updated to Spring boot 2.5 my application context won't start in the Test environment.

We have several test environments. Most tests do not need an Elastic search instance. Those that need it share an Elasticsearch test container instance.

Since the Update the creation of repositories causes some kind of query to Elasticsearch. That fails and causes the context not to load.

Is there a way to mock away the Spring Data Elasticsearch part(Not loading is not really an option to load most parts of the context)?

Should I be starting an Elasticsearch Instance for all integration tests(that seems like a little overkill, since few tests actually need it)?

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Creating repositories will create the index and mapping if it does not already exist. Do you start a new testcontainer for every class that needs it? You should only start one for **all** integration tests.

Comment: We reuse the test container but since now we only had it running for those test that needed it. Also we have a ton of different modules that run their tests in parallel and isolated.